# How to avoid gap between 2 borders?

Tags: html, css

I have SmartJobBoard installed. On search result page, I asked my designer to add border surround Priority ad and Standout ad. No border around free ad.

Between each ad there will have bottom line to separate ads. Priority ad always on top of result and the less will sort by recently posted date(Mix). When there are two ads with border then there is a gap there.
My question is how to avoid the gap?

```
<tr><td colspan="6" class="separateListing noBorder"> </td></tr>
.separateListing {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #B2B2B2;
margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}
.separateListing.noBorder {
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

You can view the html code at: [HTML source code](http://txtup.net/NPiBM)

Comment: add margin: 10px; padding: 10px

Comment: Should probably not use tables for page layout, and only as tables of data, which is what they are intended for.

Answer (score 4):

How about setting style on table: `border-collapse: collapse`